# Failing to remove items from mutable array

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

in my previous question i was given some code in order to make up this statment.

favoriteArray is an Mutable Array...

```
if (![self.favoritesArray containsObject:@"added"])
    {
        [self.favoritesArray addObject:@"added"];
    }

else
{
    [self.favoritesArray removeObject:@"added"];
}
//NSUInteger newRow = [self.favoritesArray count];

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:self.favoritesArray forKey:@"MyFavorites"];
```

however i can't get `@"added"` to be removed...
when the app loads it automatically loads added in the favorites the added text even after cleaning the code.
when i press the button it doesnt remove it.
so im guessing there is something wrong

and here is where i load it...

```
   NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSMutableArray *didContain = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   didContain = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"MyFavorites"] mutableCopy];

   if ([didContain count] == 0) {
       NSLog (@"zero");

            //
            // no favorites have ever been saved
            //


    } else {

        // load the favorites into some array you synthesized just like before
        self.tableFavoritesData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.tableFavoritesData = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"MyFavorites"] mutableCopy];
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain better what's wrong with your code?

Comment: You store/load the array in/from the user defaults? If so, how do you load it? And when & how are you checking wether `@"added"` was removed.

Comment: Your code leaks a NSMutableArray.

Comment: You alloc/init an empty NSMutableArray, and never release it but just replace it by the next one. You do this twice...

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't make much sense.

To load the array from the defaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.tableFavoritesData = [[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"MyFavorites"] mutableCopy];
```

Is all there is to do. If you don't have an empty array set up as a default value, you might check for nil:

```
if (!self.tableFavouritesData)
    self.tableFavoritesData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Or you won't be able to put *anything* in it as it will still be nil. (Alternatively use `registerDefaults:` to register a default value. This is the preferred way and you must do that before actually reading from the defaults, i.e. directly at startup).

Comment: Assuming that self.tableFavoritesData is a retaining property, you probably want to use `self.tableFavoritesData = [NSMutableArray array];` - otherwise you will leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add `@"added"` after the array creation and look if it gets removed printing the array out. Maybe you are not serializing it correctly or adding the value in the right way.